# SwiftUI - String function size(withAttributes:) throwing NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: swiftui, swift5, ios13.2

The following code is throwing this exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue renderingMode]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000007122b0'

```
let helloWorld = "Hello World"
let width = helloWorld.size(withAttributes: [.font: Font.system(size: 16.0)])
print("\(width)")
```

Has anyone figured out why this isn't working or a potential workaround?  This is happening in Swift 5 targeting iOS 13.2

Answer (score 2):

The structure `Font` is different from the class `UIFont`. The following works.

```
    let width = helloWorld.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)])
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.  However I think Apple should fix the "sizeWithAttributes" function, which is on the struct `String`, to map values to UIKit values if they are going to bridge the actual work there.

Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: `sizeWithAtributes` is a method on `NSString`